# Use wait() in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, wait, synchronized

I need to create a new JFrame in a new Thread.. When I close the JFrame I need to return a String.
The problem is that the wait() method "doesn't wait" the "notify()" of new Thread.
Thank's for your answer.

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class FinestraTesto extends Thread {

    JLabel jdescr;
    JTextArea testo;
    JPanel pannelloTasti;
    JButton bottoneInvio;
    JButton bottoneAnnulla;
    JFrame finestraTestuale;
    JPanel panAll;
    static Boolean pause = true;
    String titolo;
    String descrizione;
    private static String testoScritto = "";

    public String mostra() {
        // Create a new thread
        Thread th = new Thread(new FinestraTesto(titolo, descrizione));
        th.start();
        synchronized (th) {
                try {
                    // Waiting the end of th.
                    th.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        return testoScritto;
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.println("Fatto 1 thread");
            finestraTestuale = new JFrame(titolo);
            finestraTestuale.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 200));
            finestraTestuale.setSize(600, 200);
            Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            finestraTestuale.setLocation(
                    dim.width / 2 - finestraTestuale.getSize().width / 2,
                    dim.height / 2 - finestraTestuale.getSize().height / 2);

            panAll = new JPanel();
            panAll.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panAll, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

            bottoneInvio = new JButton("Conferma");
            bottoneAnnulla = new JButton("Annulla");
            pannelloTasti = new JPanel();
            testo = new JTextArea();
            testo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 100));
            testo.setSize(550, 100);

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
            scrollPane.setViewportView(testo);

            jdescr = new JLabel(descrizione);
            jdescr.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 50));
            jdescr.setSize(550, 50);

            pannelloTasti.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pannelloTasti,
                    BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
            pannelloTasti.add(bottoneInvio);
            pannelloTasti.add(bottoneAnnulla);

            panAll.add(jdescr);
            panAll.add(scrollPane);
            panAll.add(pannelloTasti);

            finestraTestuale.add(panAll);

            bottoneInvio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                /**
                 * metodo attivato quando c'è un'azione sul bottone
                 */
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    testoScritto = testo.getText();
                    pause = false;
                    finestraTestuale.show(false);
                    // send notify
                    notify();
                }
            });
            bottoneAnnulla.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                /**
                 * metodo attivato quando c'è un'azione sul bottone
                 */
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    pause = false;
                    testoScritto = "";
                    finestraTestuale.show(false);
                    // send notify
                    notify();
                }
            });
            finestraTestuale.show();
        }
    }

    public FinestraTesto(String titolo, String descrizione) {
        this.titolo = titolo;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are calling `notify` on the ActionListener objects, not the FinestraTesto object.

Comment: What is this, do you think you can start an arbitrary thread and work with Swing on it?

Comment: Use a modal dialog, it's what it's designed for. [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: @immibis can you explain better?

Comment: *"I need to create a new JFrame in a new Thread.. When I close the JFrame I need to return a String"* - Sounds like an dialog to me.  Swing is a single threaded environment.  There is ONE Event Dispatching Thread and ONE event queue.  Simply making Swing components in another Thread, apart from breaking the single thread rules of Swing, won't do anything.  The GUI events are published on the Event Queue and processed by the Event Dispatching Thread...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this class:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class CustomDialog
{
    private List<JComponent> components;

    private String title;
    private int messageType;
    private JRootPane rootPane;
    private String[] options;
    private int optionIndex;
    private JTextArea testo;
    public CustomDialog(String title,String descrizione)
    {
        components = new ArrayList<>();

        setTitle(title);
        setMessageType(JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        addMessageText(descrizione);
        testo = new JTextArea();
        testo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 100));
        testo.setSize(550, 100);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(testo);

        addComponent(scrollPane);
        setRootPane(null);
        setOptions(new String[] { "Send", "Cancel" });
        setOptionSelection(0);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setMessageType(int messageType)
    {
        this.messageType = messageType;
    }

    public void addComponent(JComponent component)
    {
        components.add(component);
    }

    public void addMessageText(String messageText)
    {
        components.add(new JLabel(messageText));
    }

    public void setRootPane(JRootPane rootPane)
    {
        this.rootPane = rootPane;
    }

    public void setOptions(String[] options)
    {
        this.options = options;
    }

    public void setOptionSelection(int optionIndex)
    {
        this.optionIndex = optionIndex;
    }

    public String show()
    {
        int optionType = JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION;
        Object optionSelection = null;

        if(options.length != 0)
        {
            optionSelection = options[optionIndex];
        }

        int selection = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(rootPane,
                components.toArray(), title, optionType, messageType, null,
                options, optionSelection);

        if(selection == 0)
            return testo.getText();
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would better to use [*Synchronizers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) instead of `wait` and `notify`. They're more preferable because of simplicity and safety.

> Given the difficulty of using wait and notify correctly, you should
> use the higher-level concurrency utilities instead.
>
> *Effective Java (2nd Edition), Item 69*

Comment: Swing is single threaded, if you call `wait` on an object within the EDT, it will STOP the GUI and nothing will ever be able to call `notify`....